# How can I reproduce a Series pandas dataframe in python without ValueError- truth value of series ambiguous?

Tags: python, dataframe, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test for two entries in a pandas dataframe, but I am having a bit of a hard time replicating this in python code.

When I print the pandas dataframe `md` `md.trades()['execution_venue'])`, I get:

```
0    XUBS
1    AQEU
```

My challenge is how can I write python code that will reproduce this. I do `pd.Series(['XUBS', 'AQEU'])`, and it produces the exact same as the above, but when I `assert` that the two are equal, I am getting the `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

I am doing:

```
actual_venues = md.trades()['execution_venue']
expected_venues = pd.Series(['XUBS', 'AQEU'])

pd.testing.assert_series_equal(actual_venues, expected_venues)
```

When I run the above, I am getting the `ValueError` for

Comment: Please, show what you are doing. What are you asserting exactly. It is hard to help you if you conceal that kind of thing. Also, what is this ".trades()"?

Comment: For example, if you are checking whether ``md['execution_venue']==serie``, serie being the Series you build, what you get is a Serie of booleans. All True, normally. So, if you are asserting that, then you will get complain about the fact that a Series of booleans has no truth value (it is not the Series you build that has no truth value. It is the Series of booleans that is the result of the comparison with == of two series).

Comment: So, I am speculating here, since I don't know what you did exactly. But I suspect that your true question is "how do I check that two series are identical"

Comment: I've added what I am asserting'. And yes your speculation is correct!

Comment: Everything is working now- I realised the `Name` was different for the two Series

Comment: I can't reproduce the same error here.  The error you mentioned would be exactly the one you would get if you had coded ``assert(actual_venues, expected_venues)``. But with ``pd.testing.assert_series_equal(actual_venues, expected_venues)`` what you get is (depending on how the dataframe is made. Again, I've no idea what this ".trades()" is) some complaint about the name of the series.

Comment: Ok, so with just the name it works. But that was no ValueError then. Are you sure the ValueError (about truth value of a series) was not with an ``assert(actual_venues, expected_venues)``. It should not be a possible error with ``testing.assert_series_equal``